# remove information using gsub

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to remove all the information up to the last / (the year) from this line.

"'CSF0495/DE/wb/1997'"

The code I run goes through but does not remove any information.

This it the code I run

```
date <- gsub("^[[:alnum:]]{1,}////", "",temp)
```

It goes through, but does not remove any information. Im not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You have `"////"` in your pattern, but that never occurs in the string.  I'd guess you were thinking of backslashes, which need escaping:  but forward slashes don't, so it's looking for a literal sequence of four slashes.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sub`

```
sub(".*/", "", "CSF0495/DE/wb/1997")
[1] "1997"
```

---

Or with `basename`

```
basename("CSF0495/DE/wb/1997")
[1] "1997"
```

Answer (score 3):

One of these:

**Keep `1997`**

`.*` matches any character

`.` zero or more times

`*` until the last forward slash `/`

```
date <- gsub(".*/", "", "CSF0495/DE/wb/1997")
date

[1] "1997"
```

**Remove `1997`**

`\\d{4}` matches any four digits

`$` symbol matches the end of the string

```
temp <- "CSF0495/DE/wb/1997"
date <- gsub("/\\d{4}$", "", temp)

[1] "CSF0495/DE/wb"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply extract the year, knowing that it consists of more than one `d`igits extending as far as final position in string (`$`)?

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("CSF0495/DE/wb/1997", "\\d+$")
[1] "1997"
```

Comment: I first thought also this way. But I think the op wants to remove '1997'

Answer (score 1):

I think the `gsub` or `sub` approaches in all existing answers are the most efficient. Below is just another way to reach your goal

```
> tail(scan(text = "CSF0495/DE/wb/1997", what = "", sep = "/", quiet = TRUE), 1)
[1] "1997"
```